# Is it possible to restrict which object classes a dynamically linked auxiliary class can be added to when extending the AD schema?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, schema

I've created a custom auxiliary class for the purpose of adding attributes to AD Group objects. I'm dynamically linking the auxiliary class to individual Groups. I can successfully add it to the objectClass of Group objects but I can *also* add it to other object types. I can't seem to find any clear documentation on how to restrict it to **only** Group objects. I've tried setting systemPossSuperiors/Possible Superior and it doesn't change the behavior.

It's not entirely clear that there *is* a way to restrict it but but other built in classes *seem* to demonstrate restrictions.

1. Is it possible?
2. If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Premiere support has expressed that restricting auxiliary class usage in this way is not possible.